# Является ли данный код на PHP RESTfull?

Tags: php, api, rest

Есть код:

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$data = require_once "db.php";

header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
$uri = substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 4);

if(preg_match("/\/users\/[0-9]+/", $uri)) {
    $id = explode("/", $uri)[2];

    for($i = 0; $i <= sizeof($data); $i++){
        if ($data[$i]["id"] == $id) {
            header("Status: 200");

            var_dump($data[$i]);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    header("Status: 404");

} elseif ($uri == "/users/list"){
    var_dump($data);

} elseif (preg_match("/\/delete\/[0-9]+/", $uri)){
    $id = explode("/", $uri)[2];

    for($i = 0; $i <= sizeof($data); $i++){
        if ($data[$i]["id"] == $id) {
            header("Status: 200");
            unset($data[$i]);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    header("Status: 404");

}
```

.htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

# Перенаправление с ДОМЕН на ДОМЕН/api
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /api/$1 [R=301]

#Если URI начинается с api/ то перенаправлять все запросы на index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ /index.php
```

Является ли данний Api RESTfull

Comment: Вроде как строго понятия RESTfull и нет, но вам, как минимум, не хватает аутентификации для этого "api" + делать всё-таки на ооп надо уже. Так же, RESTfull api подразумевает использование http протокола, запросы через который идут с заголовками get, post, put, delete, что даёт возможность одной url но разными заголовками выполнять различные действия (/api/users/1 + get = получить инфо, /api/users/1 + put = редактировать что-то и т.п..) а у вас для этого отдельные методы, насколько я вижу. Поэтому ответ скорее нет, чем да.

Comment: Спасибо. Всё понял.